# Can I write italics to the Python shell?

Tags: python, italics

Is it possible to write something like this:

```
>>> text_output = "Hello World."
>>> print text_output
```

...where if the text_output is printed to the Python Shell, it is printed in italics?

Comment: What do you mean by Python Shell?

Comment: Sorry, forgive my "freshness" in the subject, ha ha. Just whenever you run it, is what I meant.

Comment: Are you running it on Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am running it on Windows.

Answer (score 26):

In Python 2 or 3 if your console supports italics, e.g. [rxvt-unicode](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html) you can precede your Italic text with the [ansi escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for italics `\x1B[3m`, and then append it with `\x1B[0m` for reset/normal to return to normal characters.

```
>>> print("Normal text \x1B[3mitalic text\x1B[0m normal text")
```

[image: The above code executing and printing italics]

Comment: Does that mean if I get this: [3mHello World[23m printed, my console does not support italics? :( Drat.

Comment: This prints anything after the `\x1B[23m`. I have updated the answer to reset the characters to standard/reset after the italic text.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the standard Python shell, no.  If you want *all* output text to be in italics, you could use some GUI shell like Dreampie.  If you want the ability to actually style text (with italics, bold, etc.), you need to use some GUI library that provides that sort of ability.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell can print *Italics*.

CMD cannot.
CMD can't do ANYTHING(it's like 25 years old, what can you expect).

This works great:
`print("\x1B[3mThis text\x1B[0m is \x1B[3mitalicized!\x1B[0m")`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35378181)

Answer (score -1):

No. The print function outputs to `sys.stdout` by default. Assuming you're using something like IDLE, this will simply be echoed into IDLE. You can set some options in IDLE itself to show different font faces and sizes and whatnot, but this will modify everything, not just the output of `print` commands.

Comment: What if he's running it in Bash? I think that italics may work there.

Comment: @AlixAxel Perhaps. I've honestly never tried it. Apparently it's running on Windows, however, and I'm 99% certain that `cmd` won't cope with italicized text. Powershell, I don't know.